# How to store a result of spark dataframe in to a scala val

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe . The result of my Hive query will be always only one record with one column only . Sometimes it produce null and sometimes it produce 0 and sometimes it produce a number(bigInt)

My question I want to store the result of this single value in to a val in scala. How do i do that

```
scala> val hc = new HiveContext(sc)
hc: org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext = org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext@19e15d63

scala> val df = hc.sql("""select MAX(seq_num) as seq_num from omega.tx_records""")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [seq_num: bigint]

scala> df.show
+-------+
|seq_num|
+-------+
|   null|
+-------+
```

I want to store the ouput of df in to a string . How do i do that ?

I tried the below approach . they gave Array.

```
scala> df.collect
res2: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([null])

scala> df.take(1)
res3: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([null])

scala> df.head(1)
res4: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([null])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the **`array element`** and **`mkstring`** to generate string data!

```
val df=spark.sql("select max(seq_num)seq_num from (select 1 seq_num union all select null seq_num)e")

df.collect().map(x => x(0)).mkString
String = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are 100% sure then you can cal

```
df.collect.head.getAs[String]("seq_num")
```

to get what you want.